# Writing mathematical notation in LaTeXDraw

Tags: math-mode, pstricks

I have drawn a graph in LaTeXDraw. I need to name the vertices of the graph as v_n (where n is subscript of v). In latex document it was easy, just $v_n$ was doing the work. But how can I do it in a LaTeXDraw picture? Any help is appreciated.